# Php Mysql display joined query separately

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `content` that I join with a few other tables (`translates` and `tags`, etc). If I have 3 rows for translation and 4 rows for the tags, the result will be **12 rows** which will be bigger when there is another table.

Also displaying them on the front side becomes a bit hard. Instead of having 12 rows, I need to have 8 rows as following:

- 1 row  for the content table
- 3 rows for the translates (separated)
- 4 rows for tags (separated)

**Current behavior:** The query result is something like this: index 0 to 12 contains just a single content (with different translations and tags with the same `content_id`)

**Expected behavior:** The result must be like this: every index contains just a single content, which contains the translations and tags, something like this:

```
0 =>  content=>[...], translations=>[...], tags=>[...]
```

Is there any built-in way in `mysql` to handle such a thing? Or I must handle it in `php` via loops? How can it be possible?

Comment: Fire three separate queries to fetch the data from each table individually and then handle it in PHP

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, In that case, I miss mysql `join` feature. I think it's not the best idea.

Comment: Sometimes [Join Decomposition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch04.html) serves the purpose in a more efficient manner

Comment: if i really understand your given example , you have 1 row from the table content , and this row has 3 related row in the translates table , while those three rows are related to 4 rows in table tags ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks for the link, I am going to have a consideration about it.

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI No, both translates and tags relate to the content table.